# Google GCM demo app - Server messages not being received

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get the Google GCM demo app up and running. My android emulator makes a successful connection to the GCM server and goes on to make successful connection to my own server which is located at `http://localhost:8080/gcm-demo-server` (ie. the emulator sends the request to `http://10.0.2.2:8080/gcm-demo-server`).

However when I click 'Send message' on my server's webpage the message doesn't get delivered to the emulator. Nothing shows up in Logcat and my breakpoint in onMessage() in the GCMIntentService class doesn't get hit.

I can't understand how it can successfully register with the server, passing it's registrationId, yet when that registrationId is used to send a message back to the emulator it doesn't get received. I have not altered the demo app code.

Anyone ideas what could be going where or where I could start looking for problems as I don't even know where to start with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the network connection I was using.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have no slightest Idea which tutorial/steps you followed to make that GCM demo running.
My reccomendation is to compare your work with this link **step by step** n u'll be home :-)

http://androidv5.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/how-to-implement-google-cloud-messaging/

Moreover, you should state that when ur device/emulator connects to the server does the server  page says somehting like

**1 devices registered**

If it does, then ur server has been reached
then in this case
you would need to verify that **Are you providing correct information to the server to reach the destinatiuon device/emulator** ??

It can take time dont loose patience ;-)

**updated :**

Open the file CommonUtilities.java in gcm demo app

replace value of
**static final String SENDER_ID = “your_sender_id_from_api_console_url”;**
with ur device's sender id u obtained from this link

" https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:4815162342 "

**4815162342 in this case**

for further assistance:
In the link I mentioned scroll down to **Client Implementation**

Comment: I am using the GCM demo code from google iteself - http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html The server does say "1 devices registered" but when I click "Send message" nothing gets back to the emulator.

Comment: Do you get a response the Goolge server? If not, you have a problem connecting to the Google server (perhaps you are using a bad API key). If you get a response, does Google report success or failure? If you get a failure response, it should tell you what the problem is. If you get a successful response, perhaps the problem is in your client code (the Android App).